# iOS 17 update: contact pictures

Tags: ios, contacts

I have gone into the info section for one of my iPhone contacts and it says ‘recent photo update from (contact name)’ and looks like this:

[image]

Does this mean my contact has added the photo shown to the right of this notification to their contact details for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your contact photo is shared by going to Settings > Contacts > Share Name & Photo

If you enable the "Name & Photo Sharing" toggle then it may be shared. It shares to the people identified below the toggle.

You can set it to always ask before sharing, or to auto-share to people in your contacts.